# How can I compress ALL my JavaScript files server-side with Apache?

Tags: javascript, apache, .htaccess, compression, gzip

Hey guys,
After running Google Page Speed, my Compression Results were red. Google Page Speed said almost all my files — JS, CSS, etc. — should be compressed with gzip.

I added the following line to my .htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/css text/plain text/javascript text/xml application/xhtml+xml application/x-httpd-php
</IfModule>
```

Now the Compression Results look slighly better - yellow! However Page Speed keeps saying that I should compress *all* my JavaScript libs and plugins. I could reduce them by 65% with gzip.

Shouldn't all my JS files be compressed now when I have `text/javascript` set as `DEFLATE`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apache also uses mime type application/x-javascript, [this howto](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/compress-files-apache-mod-deflate/) explains how to set it.

Basically it says you need to use:

```
<Location />
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
</Location>
```

On a side note, you might also consider using a minifier/compressor like the [YUI compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/) or a specific compressor that integrates with your software.